# What if a meteorite hit Roswell, NM in 1947?

Tags: space, alternate-history, asteroids

I have always been interested in alternate histories that dramatically affect the course, duration, or intensity of 20th century spacefaring. One of the issues that has precluded large-scale habitation, industrialization, and militarization of outer space is the lack of motivational vision. But perhaps if a dramatic event from space had occurred in just the right window of the previous century, we would have had lunar bases by now?

With that in mind...How would the space programs of the Cold War have changed if Roswell, NM sustained a significant meteorite impact in the year 1947? I suspect that the field of asteroid defense could become a proxy battleground of it's own between technicians on opposite sides of the Iron Curtain.

How would the average citizens of the First, Second, and Third World nations be affected by man's raising a fist in defense against space?

Clarification: Let's make it just big enough to make it possible for the USAF to successfully lobby for space defense programs. Butterflies should spread outward to things like if Truman gets re-elected, but nothing severe enough to reduce the US to a post-apocalyptic state.

Additional clarification: At the time of this incident, the largest base of the SAC was located here.

Comment: This is overly broad, since you are asking two broad on its own questions.

Comment: What is so special about Roswell Nautical Mile? (I get that it's a town in the U.S.A. Extraterrestrial aliens landed there. But I have no idea what specifically makes it more special than Las Cruces or Vacaville (two other American towns.) And anyway, astronomers would immediately point out that such events are extremely rare, and moreover there is no way to develop an efficient defense system against them in any reasonable timespan.

Comment: Perhaps the impact that you describe is not sufficiently serious to prod the authorities enough. Maybe if a large US city was destroyed the fallout from that might lead to a political drive for a space defence system. Also it occurs a bit too early a hit in the 50's-60's might prompt more activity.

Comment: @AlexP I'm guessing the rationale is that Roswell was the home of Walker Air Force Base, which was the largest Air Force Base for the Strategic Air Command during the early cold war. In 1947, the SAC was in charge of the delivery of pretty much the entire nation's nuclear arsenal since nuclear ballistic missiles weren't a thing yet. So there was pretty significant value attached to Roswell at that point, although whether or not it was enough to significantly change the US space program if this happened is something I'll leave to others to debate.

Comment: @elduderino: Shouldn't this information be in the question? It's one thing to ask about some random town, and another to ask about a strategic air force base.

Comment: Even in the sometimes logic-challenged environment of Cold-War-era US military appropriations and R&D, surely *someone* would point out that instead of inventing whole new paradigms of anti-meteorite protection, it would be far easier and cheaper to just have a backup strategic command center. After all, that protects against a much wider variety of threats, and we know that it's technically feasible unlike any proposed meteorite shield.

Comment: Roswell is the site where Robert Goddard conducted his liquid fuelled rocket trials. Much more important than being the epicentre for UFO mania.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question. The VTCers obviously do not understand the difference between a story set in a world and building a world. The question asks about a possible inciting incident to led to an alternative history. That's called building aworld.